# Can't start new thread

Tags: python, multithreading, threadpool

I'm processing all the files in a directory using multiple threads to process files in parallel. It all works fine, except that threads seem to stay alive and so the thread count of the process goes up until it reaches 1K or so threads and then it throws a `thread.error can't start new thread` error. I know this error is caused by an OS-level limit on thread count.
I can't seem to figure out where the bug is that is keeping the threads alive. Any idea? Here is a minimal version of my code.

```
class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self, tasks):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.tasks = tasks
        self.daemon = True
        self.start()

def run(self):
    while True:
        func, args, kargs = self.tasks.get()
        try:
            func(*args, **kargs)
        except Exception, e: print e
        self.tasks.task_done()


class ThreadPool:
    def __init__(self, num_threads):
        self.tasks = Queue(num_threads)
        for _ in range(num_threads): Worker(self.tasks)

    def add_task(self, func, *args, **kargs):
        self.tasks.put((func, args, kargs))

    def wait_completion(self):
        self.tasks.join()


def foo(filename)
    pool = ThreadPool(32)
    iterable_data = process_file(filename)

    for data in iterable_data:
        pool.add_task(some_function, data)
    pool.wait_completion()

files = os.listdir(directory)
for file in files:
    foo(file)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are launching a new ThreadPool with 32 threads for every file. If you have a large number of files, that would be a lot of threads. And since only *one* thread at a time can be executing Python bytecode in CPython (because of the Global Interpreter Lock), it is not necessarily very fast.

Move the creation of the ThreadPool outside of the `foo()` function.

Comment: If you don't need multiple process (threads are good for i/o bound code), you also don't need to create your own threadpool: `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool`.  moving pool outside of the foo() function will fix the problem, though.

Comment: I'm using threads because the tasks involve network calls (HTTP). Using `multiprocessing` wouldn't help me much here.

Comment: @bj0 Moving the pool outside of foo() worked. Post it as an answer so I can accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @sazpaz I didn't post it as an answer because Roland mentioned it in his, he just had a lot of extra info with it, which it seems he's removed now.